# How to Close Fancy box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-1.5

I'm using Fancybox to load/display an iFrame in the fancybox. After an action in the fancybox, an AJAX request is made which responds with:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Problem here is that when this runs, there's an error (chrome): "**Failed to load resource**"

Any ideas why, and/or how to close fancybox via the ajax request w/o error?

A little more technical details. In the Parent I have jQuery 1.5 w a bunch of plugins, in the iframe I have jQuery 1.5 with rails jquery-ujs.

Thanks

Comment: Use console.log() to log parent.$ and parent.$.fancybox using the console and see if you can actually access the objects or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try making it `window.parent.$.fancybox.close();`.

Comment: Smart idea tried it. While it does close fancybox it still error's.  Is there a way to have the code above run with the error but not have JS stop parsing, some type of JS try?

Comment: I think it's an inherent error in FancyBox, I use it on our site as well, and FancyBox still throws errors, no matter what I do, but the JS doesn't stop parsing, so something else must be wrong on your side.